# SelectOneMenu width not work use bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2

This is the second post on the same subject, since the first time I did not get the result. The select width problem continues.

I'm using selectOneMenu JSF 2 and trying to change the width of it is not working.

```
<h:selectOneMenu style="width:280px" styleClass="selectpicker"`>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="A" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="B" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="C " />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Only works when I remove the `styleClass = "selectpicker"`

I've already tried adding the data-width, it also did not work. Any tips?

Comment: HTML code generates `<select id="select-one-menu-user-role" name="select-one-menu-user-role" size="1" style="width:450px"> <option>Select</option>
 <option value="1">ADMIN</option>
 <option value="2">USER</option>
</select>
` It generates an automatic value for the size, "size=1"

Answer (score 1):

You can make your style more important by adding !important to the tag. This is usually a bad idea for maintainability.

`style="width:280px !important"`

Answer (score 0):

Improve it like this

```
 style="height: 46px"
```